# File system choice, Ubuntu, and Windows in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, filesystem

(The 'Similar questions' didn't answer my question.)

My plan is to get a high powered laptop with a lots of RAM, wipe the hard drive, install Ubuntu, install VirtualBox (VBx) and install Windows 10 into VBx.

If I use the XFS file system, will that prevent Windows in VBx from accessing and using files outside of VBx?

Do I need to use ext3 or ext4 when I install Ubuntu in order for Windows in VBx to access files outside of VBx?

Just to be clear, I don't plan on doing a dual boot.

Comment: You can use any file system on the host so long as the host understands that system. VirtualBox abstracts the file system away so that machines have no understanding or awareness of the underlying system.

Comment: If you use VirtualBox's Guest Additions to access the host filesystem, then the format is irrelevant -- it can be any filesystem Ubuntu can read. It's a bit more complex, but still quite possible, without using Guest Additions -- say a socket or SSH connection. The hardest part will be installing Ubuntu on XFS. That's not for beginners, though also quite doable.

Comment: "The hardest part will be installing Ubuntu on XFS. That's not for beginners, though also quite doable. – user535733"  ---Ok, this is good to know. I'll stick with ext3 when I install Ubuntu. I'm somewhat new to Linux so don't want to bite off more than I can handle. Thx.